# Issue with binding parameters for MS SQL Server Stored Procedure in Perl DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl

Getting error while executing the stored procedure from perl. I am able to connect to the MS SQL server from perl without any issues. But when I execute the procedure with the following binding parameters I am getting the error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@id'. (SQL-42000)

this 'id' is the first parameter. When I look at the procedure it is fine.
Anyone have any thoughts on this error?

Code

```
#GetStatusDescription(?, ?, ?) - id - LONG, status - VARCHAR, description - VARCHAR
my $sth = $dbh -> prepare('exec GetStatusDescription(?, ?, ?)');
my $str1, my $str2;
my $intid = 11122;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
$sth->bind_param(1, $intid, DBI::SQL_INTEGER); 
$sth->bind_param_inout(2, \$str1, DBI::SQL_VARCHAR); 
$sth->bind_param_inout(3, \$str2, DBI::SQL_VARCHAR); 
$sth->execute() or die $dbh -> errstr;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're calling to a stored procedure, those don't take parentheses in SQL Server. that is, you want:

```
my $sth = $dbh -> prepare('exec GetStatusDescription ?, ?, ?');
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind marking it as the answer, that would be great. Thanks!